# Spring Boot - IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping error on controllers

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and I have controller that has 2 GET methods (simplified).

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/cars")
public List<CarsResponse> getCarsByRegion(
        @RequestParam("regionNumber") short regionNumber,
        @RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate,
        @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate) {
    
    ...
}
```

Its endpoint is http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/cars/regions?startDate=2016-09-21&endDate=2026-10-01

and another GET method:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/cars")
public List<CarsResponse> getCarsBetween(
        @RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate,
        @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate) {
    
    ...
}
```

Its endpoint is http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/cars/regions?regionNumber=12&startDate=2016-09-21&endDate=2026-10-01

When I run my application, I get error:

**IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'carsController' method CarsController.getCarsByRegion(Date, Date)**

I understand why this is happening.  It is because both methods are mapped to `/cars` endpoint and for that reason, Spring does not know which one I am trying to use.

But I dont know how to solve this.  How should my endpoints be defined in order to be able  to handle this?  Obviously, both of the above methods need to call `/cars` endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this before I posted the question (thanks to this URL https://www.arquitecturajava.com/requestparam-spring-mvc-y-sus-opciones/) but it took me
a while, so I decided to create question and provide answer regardless.

The solution I am going with is to use `params` in `@GetMapping` or whatever mapping you use

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cars", params = {"regionNumber", "startDate", "endDate"})
public List<CarsResponse> getCarsByRegion(
        @RequestParam("regionNumber") short regionNumber,
        @RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate,
        @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate) {
    
    ...
}
```

, and same for the other method:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cars", params = {"startDate", "endDate"})
public List<CarsResponse> getCarsBetween(
        @RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate,
        @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate) {
    
    ...
}
```